# Empty $_POST array in PHP 5.2.6 / IIS CGI

Tags: php, iis

I am running into a very strange issue with PHP 5.2.6 w/ IIS on Windows XP (have tried both CGI and ISAPI). I am running a fresh installation with the default php.ini settings.

First, assume the following (ugly, but effective) HTML code:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="test1" value="foo" />
<input type="hidden" name="test2" value="bar" />
<input type="submit">
</form>
<br /><br />
<pre>
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
</pre>
```

When the form is submitted, I expect it to bring out an array containing the two hidden variables. Instead all I see is an empty array. If I change the form method to "get" and change print_r($_POST) to print_r($_GET), I see the array items with no problem.

I have tried variations such as `<?php print file_get_contents('php://input'); ?>` and `<?php echo print_r($HTTP_POST_VARS); ?>` to no avail. Any ideas where the problem might lie?

Answer (score 2):

Well, if it's any consolation your code works as intended in PHP5 with Apache.

A quick Google revealed a couple other people with the same problem but no definitive solution - closest thing was [this](http://bytes.com/archives/php/389664-_post-problem-php5-iis)...

> Check your IIS configuration and see what verbs are permitted for PHP.
>   My guess is that POST isn't included. You should have GET and POST
>   enabled at a minimum, or just make your life easy and allow all verbs.

Make sure you update your question if you find a solution; I'm sure other people will benefit.

Comment: Thanks Flubba, but I have all verbs enabled in IIS. Still unable to receive POST vars in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just had the same issue.

The PHP.ini file is picky...make sure you don't have "GB" where it should be "G". I had my "post_max_size" at 1GB instead of 1G, PHP ran fine, except for POST requests.