# PHP $_POST does not work

Tags: php, iis, post, get

I'm working a web application with PHP.
Something wrong is happening that I have never seen before. `$_GET` is working well, but `$_POST` does not work exactly. Imagine the form below:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="title" />
   <input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
```

As you see, I've used post for method attribute of the form. In this case, the code below will return error:

```
<?php
$sentData = $_POST['title'];
echo($sentData);    
?>
```

Error message:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: title in ...
```

But If I had used `$_GET` in php scripts and `get` in the html form codes, everything would work without any error.

There are something more strange.

1. There are just one form that returns no error while I'm using POST, other forms return error.
2. When I run this application locally (with Xampp - Apache 2.2) everything works fine without any error, but whenever I run the application an the remote server (IIS 7), I get these errors and problems.

Comment: It is not an error it is a Notice. You can disable those.

Comment: @Dynamicus If the notice is that the variable you need does not exist, disabling the notice is not really an option.

Comment: @Dynamicus: The E_NOTICE can be suppressed, but whether you should or not is another matter. The OP is expecting this value to be populated so hiding the 'error' is really not going to help at all. ...Have you tried `print_r($_POST)` to see if anything is returned?

Comment: what does `var_dump($_POST);` say?

Comment: He doesn't even accept any answers, so will be hard for people to bother answering his question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Empty $_POST array in PHP 5.2.6 / IIS CGI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313188/empty-post-array-in-php-5-2-6-iis-cgi)

Comment: And so you've rated the question -1, because he hasn't accepted any answer so far? To be honest - the two answers on this question so far should be downrated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I changed the server that my files were located on it. I tried them on another server (same OS), and everything worked fine.
I could not get what was the reason... This was the first time that I was getting this unknown error.
However, thank you all for your suggestions and comments.

Comment: Well, I don't have that luxery and I'm having the same problems. Though it only occurs when I try to access it via the internet. If I try to aproach it via the LAN everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

so i would approach this in a couple of different ways:

1. @Dynamicus is correct, this is only a 'Notice' and not a fatal error (at least you didn't say so in the question), so this may be a difference in your .ini config or with a config definition to suppress errors like so 'error_reporting(0);'
2. You may want to make a back up of your current running .ini on your local and on the server and copy the working one over to your server and restart Apache and see if that makes a difference.
3. Why the indexed array (ie $_POST) is producing a warning is somewhat bizarre, but do a "print_r($_POST);" or a "var_dump($_POST);" to see the contents or if anything is off.

if you're using a framework or something that does routing, this could be something to look into.

i hope this helps and there are more settings for error reporting [here]  http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 0):

Your input element needs both a name and value property.