# Php 7 form doesn't work with enctype="multipart/form-data" and method="post"

Tags: php, html, file-upload, iis-8

I am using PHP 7.0.9 with IIS 8. I have a html form to upload an image. The method is `POST`, the action is correct, and enctype is "multipart/form-data". However, when I submit the form, the page hangs, as if it was trying to upload the selected file endlessly - it weight about 30kb, not a big deal...

Here is my form :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="text" name="textInput" id="textInput">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is upload.php :

```
<?php

echo "ok<br/>";
var_dump($_POST);

?>
```

As is, when I click on "Upload Image", the page hangs as if it was uploading the file endlessly.

But if I remove the `enctype` or if I change the action by `get`, the form is submited and prints :

```
ok
array(0) { }
```

The `$_POST` array is obviously empty, but why doesn't it works with `enctype="multipart/form-data"` ?

**FYI**:

```
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 20M
max_file_uploads = 20
upload_tmp_dir = C:\Windows\temp
```

...and C:\Windows\temp is writeable for Everyone. Yes, the group Everyone - I am really annoyed by this, and I don't want any rights problem.

**Some tests later...**

If I use :

```
<form action="upload.php" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="text" name="textInput" id="textInput">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

The result is :

```
ok
array(3) { ["fileToUpload"]=> string(13) "imageName.png" ["textInput"]=> string(4) "blah" ["submit"]=> string(12) "Upload Image" }
```

It seems to be a problem between the method and the enctype.

**EDIT**

For what it worth, I think it's definitly a IIS problem: when I look in the IIS log I see the request for the form :

```
2017-01-16 13:28:19 X.X.X.X GET /testupload.html - 80 - X.X.X.X Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.2;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/55.0.2883.87+Safari/537.36 - 304 0 0 1140
```

But nothing is written when I submit the form; so I don't even know if IIS is receiving the request.

Comment: Have you tried with a different browser? Does it work with input type text only if you ommit the input type file?

Comment: I cannot replicate it with the same php version, but with Apache instead of IIS.

Comment: @Blackbam I tried it with Chrome 55 and Internet Explorer 10.

Comment: Whats actually happening - are the browsers just freezing? Have you checked permissions for upload directory? Maybe the file cannot be moved there (if form submission with text only works?) ?

Comment: @Blaatpraat The code can't be simplier; I am pretty sure the problem is coming from some IIS misconfiguration...

Comment: @Blackbam The browser doesn't freeze, it's really as if it was waiting for some answer from the server - you know with the turning icon in the tab. And to answer your previous question, If I remove the file upload part, the problem is still there; but if I remove the enctype, the form is submited, but var_dump($_POST) prints an empty array.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313188/empty-post-array-in-php-5-2-6-iis-cgi ? You also could try to read the input with php://input and check if input is there and it is just a misconfiguration of $_POST?

Comment: @Blackbam no change with php://input. I also tried with 20000000 instead of 20M and allowed every verbs for php files in iis, nothing change neither.

Comment: Probably IIS misconfiguration for POST?

Comment: No, I have other forms in ASP.Net which are working... so the problem is a combination of php, forms, post, form-encoding and IIS. When I see such problems I think of becoming a lumberjack :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133094/discussion-between-gobes-and-blackbam).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the culprit was Glimpse. I absolutely don't know why, but once I had removed every traces of the plugin in the web.config, upload via PHP worked again.

Answer (score -1):

"I cannot replicate it with the same php version, but with Apache instead of IIS"

Take a look on your IIS firewall.

Comment: If you want to answer a comment, post a comment. Also, there is no built-in firewall in IIS.

Comment: @ArthurSPITZNAGEL — If you don't have enough reputation to comment, then just don't comment and move on. Don't post a comment as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

use $_FILES (for files) instead of $_POST

Comment: $_POST should not be empty anyways he said he tried